# Saving Viewstate on Server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, viewstate

What is the best way to save view state on server?

Is it a good idea to use a WCF service to save the view state on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we talking about ASP.NET view state? Why do you need WCF to store view state on the server? ASP.NET provides its own methods to store view state on the server:

- You can override `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium` and `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium` on your `Page`.
- You can override `PageStatePersister` property of your `Page` (or in custom `PageAdapter`). This property by default returns `HiddenFieldPageStatePersister` but you can change it to `SessionPageStatePersister` or implement custom `PageStatePersister`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479403.aspx) you can read about PageStatePersisters.

Comment: For the most part you would probably want to store the view state somewhere other than the session, which by default times out after 20 minutes of activity.

Comment: Yes. I am talking about ASP.net viewstate. I need WCF because my sql server is behind a firewall and my web server is in the DMZ.

Comment: In such case you can use described methods or custom persister to communicate with your WCF service and pass view state as byte array. Or you can store view state in session on web server.

Answer (score 1):

There's a project on CodeProject that you should look at called [Efficient Server-Side View State Persistence](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ViewStatePersistance.aspx). This meets the following criteria:

- The View State needs to be persisted
  on the server.
- The View State persistence mechanism
  needs to be identified by a specific
  user session.
- The persisted View State artifact
  must not be allowed to remain
  forever.
- The persisted View State should be
  able to be enabled and disabled on a
  page by page bases.
- Different persistence mechanisms
  should be able to be used.
- Page development and structure should
  not be modified.